# Crystal report sending a parameter to specify

Tags: c#, sql, crystal-reports

I'm creating a program in C# that links to a database. the problem that I am having is that I want to set up a crystal report on the sale of a certain customer( all the times one person bought an item). I want to choose that person from a data bound combo box. then click on the button and have the report shows only that one persons purchases.
I created the crystal report that shows all the clients unfortunately.

How do I send a specific client into that Crystal report?

Comment: why not retrieve data for single user only from database?

Comment: using a query? and how would i get the report to use that query?

Comment: you must have attached datasource to your report,right?All you need to do is to filter your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A SQL query with parameter is your best choice if you want to use a combo box. Here is a little example of how you could do it:

```
string customer = ComboBox.Text;
string connectionString =
ConsoleApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
connection.Open();
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.customer LIKE @Name", connection))
{
//
// Add new SqlParameter to the command.
//
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Name", customer));
```

...and so on. You can also add a parameter to the report itself and you will be prompted for that value every time you run the report. That might be a little easier and I'm not sure if it's really any slower than the other option.

Hope that helps,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Like Anand said filtering on the db will give better performance for your report, but if you want to send a paramenter to crystal reports you just has to set it via code

```
myDataReport.SetParameterValue("parameterName", parameterValue);
```